# invalid cast Exception, asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

again !
The error I thought before, wasn't the right one. I used the correct method for displaying the data. But the real issue is on my asp.net page.
when i take data from the database, there are some columns that are boolean !
when i try to do :

```
<td><asp:Checkbox ID="sup_lcked" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("sup_blocked") %>' /></td>
```

that's where i got the so invalid cast.
And what i don't understand is other columns of the same type in the database work perfectly but this one not !

thanks

Comment: What was the exact error? What did you cast to? Please show your code. It looks like you should be using `ExecuteReader` or similar, given that you've effectively got two "columns" in the result set. This has nothing to do with ASP.NET, btw - you could see exactly the same result in a console app. (Indeed, I'd recommend writing a short but complete console app to demonstrate the problem.)

Comment: use `ExecuteReader` or `DataAdapter` to populate data

Answer (score 1):

Using [DataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select facture, count(l.le_ville) as nbre from table group by l.le_ville", con);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

 if (dr .HasRows)
        {
            while (dr .Read())
            {
                string facture=Convert.toString(dr[0]);
                string nbre =Convert.toString(dr[1]);
            }
        }
```

Using [DataAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select facture, count(l.le_ville) as nbre from table group by l.le_ville", con);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
if(dt.Rows.Count>0)
{
      string facture=Convert.toString(dt.Rows[0][0]);
      string nbre =Convert.toString(dt.Rows[0][1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments you should use the `ExecuteReader` or `DataAdapter` methods. Here are some examples:

### Usage of the ExecuteReader method

```
public class FactureInfo
{
    public int Facture {get; set;}
    public int Nbre {get; set;}
}

public IList<FactureInfo> GetFactureInfo()
{
    DbConnection conn = null;
    DbDataReader reader = null;

    try
    {
        conn = new OleDbConnection(
            "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " + 
            "Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("MyDataFolder/MyAccessDb.mdb"));
        conn.Open();

        DbCommand cmd = 
            new OleDbCommand("select facture, count(l.le_ville) as nbre
                from table
                group by l.le_ville", conn);

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        var factures = new List<FactureInfo>();
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            var factureInfo= new FactureInfo();
            factureInfo.Facture = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("facture"));
            factureInfo.Nbre = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("nbre"));

            factures.Add(factureInfo);
        }

        return factures;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (reader != null)  reader.Close();
        if (conn != null)  conn.Close();
    }

    return null;
}
```

### Usage of the DataAdapter method

```
public DataSet GetFactureInfo()
{
    DbConnection conn = null;
    DataSet dataSet = null;

    try
    {
        conn = new OleDbConnection(
            "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " + 
            "Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("MyDataFolder/MyAccessDb.mdb"));
        conn.Open();

        DbDataAdapter dataAdapter = 
            new OleDbDataAdapter("select facture, count(l.le_ville) as nbre
                from table
                group by l.le_ville", conn);

        dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

        return dataSet;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (dataAdapter != null)  dataAdapter.Dispose();
        if (conn != null)  conn.Dispose();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Note that in the example I used an Access database and OLEDB connection, however this will work the same with other kind of databases. Just change the connectionstring and instantiate the correct type of class (e.g. SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlDataReader and SqlDbAdapter to connect to an MS SQL Server database).